# Handle Transaction in Codeception

Tags: transactions, codeception

I'm using Codeception as my testing framework and currently I'm at the point that there is transaction inside my code but Codeception already opens a transaction to clear database when tests are done.

Of course, I have a problem now that I can't open a transaction inside an active transaction?

Did anyone had the same problem and how he managed to deal with it without a big refactoring/work around?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I sorted it out in a different way.

I created an InMemory Transaction Connection which basically locking the transaction according to boolean variable and bind the InMemoryTransaction in case of tests